# Margin removes background in a web page

Tags: html, css

I have two html pages (`index.html` and `top.html`) and this sample from the css file:

```
 body{
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #93a5cf , #e4efe9)
  margin: 0;
}
```

`index.html` has both no margin and the correct background color while `top.html` has no margin but also no background. If I remove the margin properties the background is as it should on both pages. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I put a heading and the the background changed to something weird. https://prnt.sc/hx31y3

Answer (score 1):

You are missing semicolon.
It should be

```
body{
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #93a5cf , #e4efe9);
  margin: 0;
}
```

Add ; before margin

Comment: I already have that I just missed it here. The semicolon is there but the background is still blank.

Comment: Are you sure? Try to inspect the element. If you are using Chrome, you can read this https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/